# PHP PDO could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-7.1

I need to use PHP PDO to connect to a MariaDB database to do work. But when I run the php file through the processor it throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Users
\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\...\...
\dashboard.php:16

Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\...
\...\dashboard.php(16): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', 
NULL, NULL, Array)

#1 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects
\...\...\dashboard.php on line 16
```

I have the PDO drivers enabled in php.ini

```
 extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
 extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
 extension=php_pdo_obdc.dll
```

Comment: Look at that: `PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', 
NULL, NULL, Array)` That is what your code tries to do (stack trace). What does it tell you?

Comment: @arkascha It tries to create a connection, even with the NULL values filled it still fails giving the 'could not find driver' error.

Comment: Just a thought ... do you have the actual .dll fiie in the project? In linux this error always appear if you don't have the extension installed (windows is unable to find the .dll that you are registering in php.ini)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, when I ran phpinfo() inside the php file I found:

```
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

Turns out the process that was executing the file was ignoring the php.ini file.